# Gesture conflicts between NavigationDrawer and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a `NavigationDrawerActivity` with the following layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_drawerlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_listview"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/navigationDrawerBackgroundColor" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` gets replaced by a `Fragment` that is the currently selected item from the `NavigationDrawer`'s `ListView`.

The display works well, `NavigationDrawer` works well, but when the `Fragment` contains a `ViewPager` with an indicator, such as:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <me.shkschneider.skeleton.ui.viewpager.ViewPagerCircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/viewpagercircleindicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spaceSmallish" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get weird behavior (mostly) when I try to swipe back (to the left): the `View` inside the `ViewPager` slides like half-the distance and then resets to its position, making it hard to swipe to the previous `Fragment`.

I noticed that it happens only when the starting point of my finger was on the left side of the screen (which is where the `NavigationDrawer` is), however I see no `NavigationDrawer` movement whatsoever.

This happens on my Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1 and my Moto X running Android 4.4.4.

1. Are both UI elements truly compatible?
2. Am I missing a `Listener` or something to prevent this behavior / how to avoid it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I implemented this differently with Android Design library and that problem is now gone.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: The design library exposes a `DrawerLayout` with a complete tutorial. Link in the answer.